# Connected components of a given set

Tags: general-topology, geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $H_1,H_2,H_3, H_4$ be four hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ . I need to find the maximum number of connected components of $\mathbb{R}^3-H_1\cup...\cup H_4$. I have no idea how to visualise it. This is easy to do in $\mathbb{R}^2$ . Also can we construct a general formula for maximum number of connected componets In $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $m$ hyperplanes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is known as the [cake number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cake_number).

In general, the maximum number of components into which $m$ hyperplanes inside  $\mathbb R^n$ cut $\mathbb R^n$ is:

$\binom{m}{n}+\binom{m}{n-1}+\dots+ \binom{m}{1}+\binom{m}{0}$.

Comment: Thank you ! This really helped

Comment: sure, no problem.